# Android keeping StringSet in SharedPreferences does not work

Tags: java, android, set, sharedpreferences

I want to keep "favourites" records in SharedPreferences, but something is going wrong. In SharedPreferences independent on that, what I am doing, there is always one record. the first I decided to add. I was checking, but e.g removing it works well, but after complete restarting, or reinstalating app, problem comes back. I add 3 records, restart app, there is first I added. I remove it, add another one, restart app, there is the first from before lunch. I remove it, restart app, this one still is there. I remove it, add another one, restart app, previous one is on the list. I tried e.g:

My Adapter, which is displaying one record I want to keep:

```
public class DayFavouriteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    private String[] values;

    public DayFavouriteAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.day_favourite, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View day = inflater.inflate(R.layout.day_favourite, parent, false);

        final SharedPreferences prefs = Data.getPreferences(context, null);
        final Set<String> favs = prefs.getStringSet(Data.favourites, new HashSet<String>());

        day.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                final Activity activity = FavouriteActivity.getInstance();
                AlertDialog.Builder deleting = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                deleting.setTitle("Deleting");
                deleting.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                deleting.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        boolean a = favs.remove(favs.toArray(new String[]{})[position]); //a is always true, misstake is impossible
                        Log.d("AC", favs.toString() + ""); //returns correct result
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.putStringSet(Data.favourites, favs);
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.apply();
                        Log.d("AC", prefs.getStringSet(Data.favourites, new HashSet<String>()) + ""); //returns correct result
                        activity.recreate(); //after this, everything is cool.
                    }
                });
                deleting.setNegativeButton("No", null);
                deleting.show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return day;
    }
}
```

My Data.java (if needed):

```
public abstract class Data {
    public static final String favourites = "favourites";
    public static final SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context, String s) {
        if (s==null) {
            return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        }
        return context.getSharedPreferences(s, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

I am using a few ways to do it, but any works well.

Comment: You say "problem comes back", which problem. Please add more explanation

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast I added more explanation you were pleasing.